# How to define and call global methods in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic3

How do I define and call global methods?

For example:

```
   showLoading() {
      console.log('App has start loading');
   }    

   hideLoading() {
      console.log('App has finished loading');
   }
```

Instead of defining and calling these on every component, how would I define them on app.component.ts and call them from child components?

Thanks

Comment: Make them static?

Comment: @echonax And how do I call them/reference to app.component from child components?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305104/5706293

Comment: Is the issue solved?